# Cropping from a point from CIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a CIImage, and when I touch a point on the display (Shown in the red box (lets say `x: 10`, `y :20`)), I need to crop that part of the image.

Since, it is a CIImage, the coordinates starts from Bottom-Top.

So, my question is when I select a Point on the image (Lets say the Red box shown on the image), How can I crop the image with relation to the CIImage ?

Note: Since the CIImage is reversed I basically want to how to convert my touch point which was `x:10, y:20` so it can select the correct point from CIImage. Hope I made the question clear.

[image]

Update

```
let myCropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
myCropFilter!.setValue(myInputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
myCropFilter!.setValue(CIVector(x: 10, y: 20, z: 100, w: 300), forKey: "inputRectangle")
let myOutputImage : CIImage = myCropFilter!.outputImage!
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Would you post some code?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Updated with code.

Comment: What do you many by "I have a CIImage"? A CIImage is not something you can display on the screen, or that the user can tap. It is an element in a rendering chain. Your code creates `myOutputImage`, but that is not something the user can see or tap. You have not explained what it is that the user sees or is tapping — but everything depends on that.

Comment: I do understand that CImage cannot be displayed. My question is only how to reverse the CImage so I can crop the image at the desired points.

Comment: I don't see why you need to "reverse" anything. Cropping a CIImage just works. If you don't relate the CIImage to what is displayed, there is no sense in which the position of a tap is meaningful.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Waiting for your comment, i have already added my code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your problem